# Why does “recommend deletion” have variable number of reasons?

Tags: support, review-queues, low-quality-answers

I'm just getting to be familiar to the **Low quality answers** review queue and I have observed that sometimes the option **Recommend deletion** has multiple reasons:

> - No comment needed
> - This is commentary on another post, not an answer
>   [...]
> - This is a “thank you” comment
>   [...]
> - This is an “I’m having this problem, too” comment
>   [...]
> - This is a different question posted as an answer
>   [...]
> - This is a link-only answer (and not spam)
>   [...]

However, sometimes there are only the *"no-comment"* and *"link-only"* possibilities. What is the reason behind this mechanism?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the comments, it was figured out, that the two-options case is for old answers (*but it is not yet known how old it is*).

It is a bit strange to me that old (possible) **Low quality answers** do not need the same detailed justification for deletion that newer ones. It is more strange, that the *"link-only"* option still keeps on. However, my wondering about this practice is not a [support](/questions/tagged/support) but a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) question.

Comment: The answers with only two options are quite old ones, but I don't know how old they have to be.

Comment: Relevant overmeta post about the reviewing process of this queue: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing/180029#180029 . Just in case you hadn't seen it. Not that it answers this particular question though.

Comment: Doesn't the dialog state something like "this question is old and comments will not help anymore" when there are only two options? I can't check since I've spend all my reviews today.

Comment: @BDL: you are right: there is *This answer has been on the site for quite a while now; it probably won't benefit from commentary. If you think it could be fixed, go back and leave a comment explaining the problem.*